Need help to resolve - Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file in React Native
I could not figure out the reason for this same error, I've changed my JDK from jdk 8, 11, 17, and 20 still the error was not resolved. Deleted my android/ folder still I did not solve. I think mine is a bit different from others whi had this same error.
This is the error i have been having:
*Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Benj\projects\TikTokClone\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Benj.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\e34934ll5fugwo6b0s7f5a19r).

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 64*

Here is my android/build.gradle:


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}



This is my android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties


distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists



My android/setting.gradle


rootProject.name = 'TikTok'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'




The error means that you try to run a Gradle 7.5 build with Java 20.
As you can see at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html this is not supported, but only up to Java 18.
Whatever you select as project JDK in your IDE is pointless unless you configured your IDE to use your project JDK to run Gradle. Typically, it will use JAVA_HOME by default instead.
Make sure you run Gradle with a compatible Java version, then the error goes away.

Have you check about permissions

Your build environment were unmatched and incompatible.
There are a bundle of build tool/development kit that compatible at the time project was run. In java please refer from this matrix
You can refer from my case below. Which my gradle wrapper must be 7.3.3 and my JDK must be 11.0.23

In my case
I run in terminal
yarn android --variant release

The error was
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Volumes/boxfan/myapp/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/ytachy/.gradle/caches/7.3.3/scripts/bu0sqtwsl6ntabs0nuv0zloyh).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 31s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installRelease -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Volumes/boxfan/myapp/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/ytachy/.gradle/caches/7.3.3/scripts/bu0sqtwsl6ntabs0nuv0zloyh).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 31s

    at makeError (/Volumes/boxfan/myapp/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Volumes/boxfan/myapp/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Volumes/boxfan/myapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Volumes/boxfan/myapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Which I checked is
java -version


OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-21.0.3.9.1 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.3.9.1 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)


Then I change my $JAVA_HOME via the smart way in this Medium site . Now it convert to
java -version


OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.23+9 (build 11.0.23+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.23+9 (build 11.0.23+9, mixed mode)



Build project and run again

yarn android --variant release

And it works like a charm. Peace!
